# Flutter Project: MainActivity.java is missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I am trying to create a Platform Channel in a Flutter project to access Android-specific java code. I am creating a new Flutter Application project in Android Studio and following [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) tutorial which mentions:

> 1- Navigate to the directory holding your Flutter app, and select the android folder inside it. Click OK.
>
> 2- Open the MainActivity.java file located in the java folder in the Project view.

However, the project only contains MainActivity.kt and not Java:

[image]

I tried creating a new activity inside the java folder manually by using context menu>New>Activity but it doesn't work.

---

**EDIT:**

The best solution for this (if you can create a new project) is to uncheck "Include Kotlin support for Android code" when you are setting up the project. This automatically creates MainActivity.java. The same goes for Objective-C and Swift. If you want to use Objective-C, uncheck "Include Swift support for iOS code"

[image]

Comment: When you create your project, you get the choice to choose the Android native language. The default recently changed from Java to Kotlin. If you prefer Java, just choose that when creating a new project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply create the class file MainActivity.java with the Java code and delete the Kotlin one.  It should work:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the imports required? Using `this` seems no longer to be correct.

Comment: import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;  .....and then GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(new FlutterEngine(this));

Answer (score 32):

If you are here because you are following the steps for setting up [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging), you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634673/5365164) and just create the `Application.kt` file (instead of Java) next to your `MainActivity.kt` file. Here it is:

```kotlin
package com.example.yourapp

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
flutter create -a java .
```

Try this command. with '.' at end. It represent current project directory.
apply this command from project root folder.
This command will try to recreate android project with java (this will setup your MainActiviy.java). It won't affect currently setup manifest or any other firebase related setup.

Comment: If the project already has minactivity.kt, then it needs to be deleted manualy. after or later this command.

Comment: i deleted `MainActivity.kt` and create `MainActivity.java` just like this and now my App cant be rebuilted.

Answer (score 5):

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuXi2.png)

Create MainActivity.java and remember place it in this direction: **Android/App/src/MainActivity.java**

Answer (score 2):

If you project is missing the mainactivity file in that case you can run this command

```
flutter create .
```

the above command will add any missing files related to your project for all the platforms that your project supports,including mainActivity.java and incase you want to change the platform language e.g java to kotlin for android then you can specify the language using the `-a` flag

```
flutter create -a kotlin .
```

this will create a kotlin directory and add the missing files adding a dot at the end indicates the project name would not be altered

Note: This command wont work if your project directory name has (space,-,Uppercase letter) it should strictly be in lowercase and separated with _ instead of space.

Answer (score 1):

The default android language for flutter is Kotlin, but you can change it in the beginning when you create a flutter project, by using the below techniques,

1.

[image: When you are creating a Flutter project in the Android Studio]

2. Or you can use,

   flutter create -a java